# postgresql view

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [postgresql view with max min with id](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9798/postgresql-view-with-max-min-with-id)

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE trans (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    trans_date date,
    trans_time time        
);
```

I want to have the following view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW daily_trans AS
SELECT trans_date,
    max(trans_time) as first, 
    min(trans_time) as last,
    calculate_status(min(trans_time), max(trans_time)) as status 
GROUP BY trans_date
```

with columns that specify the ids of the max and min trans_time.

How do I do that?

Comment: Notice that this appears to be a programming question only, has been asked (and well answered) on [so] at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648355/postgresql-view-with-max-min-with-id and should be closed here. Any agreement on these thoughts?

Comment: Yes, it's been answered already.  This can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I hope the dupe gets migrated here - we are not *just* an 'administration' site despite the name and anything involving windowing functions [is on-topic here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq). Will check with SO if they want to keep this or are willing to migrate.

Comment: Hey guys thank you for migrating my question. I was divided where to post it.

Comment: @RandomJoe I think it is better here, and it looks like SO were happy to send it over. btw, it is not usually a good idea to post exact duplicates across sites - sometimes you might legitimately want a programmers perspective and a db expert perspective on the same problem, but then I'd expect the questions to be tailored a little for the site - does that sound reasonable?

Comment: @JackDouglas You are right. Thanks for moving it here :).

Comment: Ended up to be a complete dupe. Delete it ..